# Remove same permutations from different multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Sample Data:**

```
val1,val2
1,1
1,2
1,3
2,1
2,2
2,3
3,1
3,2
3,3
4,1
```

**Excepted ouput:**

```
val1,val2
1,2
1,3
2,3
4,1
```

The Logic :
Remove the same val permutations and retain the min val1 data.
e.g:
Remove `1,1` because they're same.
Remove `2,1` because `1,2` exist...etc

**Data SQL Script :**

```sql
CREATE TABLE T
    (val1 int, val2 int)
;

INSERT INTO T
    (val1, val2)
VALUES
    (1, 1),
    (1, 2),
    (1, 3),
    (2, 1),
    (2, 2),
    (2, 3),
    (3, 1),
    (3, 2),
    (3, 3),
    (4, 1)
;
```

[SQL Server 2012 | db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=d9684c837b12e978f99a62204348d098)

Comment: @VBoka it's not limit any one rdbms,but you're right,it'll confuse people to answer.

Comment: I know there is no explicit ordering, but is the order of records selected important? Eg:, if (2,1) appears before (1,2), would you want to include (2,1) or (1,2)?

Comment: @rohitvats: "appears before"? There is no inherent order in a table. A table is considered an unordered set of data. So, there would have to be some column (e.g. a sortkey, a date, an ID issued in ascending order) to represent an order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one way to apply the two conditions:

```
select val1, val2
from mytable
where val1 <> val2 --Remove 1,1 because they're same.
and not exists -- Remove 2,1 because 1,2 exists, etc.
(
  select null
  from mytable other
  where other.val1 < other.val2
  and other.val1 = mytable.val2
  and other.val2 = mytable.val1
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you simply need -

```
SELECT val1, val2
FROM T
WHERE val1 <> val2 AND val1 < val2
```

[Demo.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=36d01343a402a761147cb70747862b1c)

Comment: A good idea on first glance, but you'd dismiss 4|1, even when 1|4 doesn't exist in the table.

Comment: thanks first,I upvote this! but like @Thorsten Kettner says. I updated question.

Answer (score 1):

I think this one should work (SQL Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/252a82/44))

```
SELECT DISTINCT CASE
              WHEN val1 < val2 THEN val1
              ELSE val2
            END AS theMin,
            CASE
              WHEN val1 < val2 THEN val2
              ELSE val1
            END AS theMax
FROM   t
WHERE  val1 <> val2
ORDER  BY themin ASC,
          themax ASC
```

Comment: If only 4|1 and not 1|4 existed in the table, you'd still return 1|4. This was not requested, but may still appeal to the OP :-)

Comment: BTW: Many DBMS feature `LEAST` and `GREATEST` for finding the minimum and maximum of two (or more) values.